# Recommeneded method to monitor rotary position and speed of machinery shaft

Tags: hall-effect, rotary-encoder, shaft-position

I am building a piece of industrial machinery that will operate between 10-200 RPM. I would like to know the rotational position and speed of the shaft (2in diameter steel crankshaft). I am currently considering building a small attachment for my shaft in order to mount on a rotary encoder as pictured below ? I also have considered mounting a trigger wheel with hall effect sens to the shaft as seen in the second picture. I am sure there is a standard procedure for monitoring shaft position in industrial equipment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are [large rotary encoders that a 2" shaft fits into.](https://www.directindustry.com/prod/ami-elektronik/product-167912-1822186.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will need an absolute position rotary encoder. There are hollow shaft options that allow the shaft to enter the encoder.

As recommended by the other users, I can use a product similar to these:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A 360° absolute rotary encoder would be the right choice for monitoring the speed and rotary position of a crankshaft.

A standard incremental rotary encoder would require a 'homing' routine to establish zero position after every power off.